# Exporting 1000s of maps into PDF in single step using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder, pdf, data-driven-pages

I have a raster of a district and shp of roads and town boundaries.  I have made the grid index for it and now I want to export 2000 of the grids as a separate PDF map in which each grid is zoomed.

Can you either guide me in ModelBuilder or send me the Python script for this?

Comment: Assuming you're using ArcGIS, you can use Data Driven Pages for this, no need to get into Model Builder or Python.

Comment: i have 2000 of maps

Comment: any script for automatic export of all these maps at once ?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  If you wish to try and do this using ArcPy rather than Data Driven Pages or ModelBuilder then you should [edit] your question to say that, but be aware that for questions that involve code you will need to present a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: "*i have 2000 of maps*" then use Data Driven Pages.  "*any script for automatic export of all these maps at once ?*" no need, use Data Driven Pages and the standard print dialog will let you print all 2000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up Data Driven Pages. This is a good source for information on that: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/page-layouts/creating-data-driven-pages.htm

Then, you can do the following steps:

1 Verify that Data Driven Pages are enabled and that ArcMap is in layout view.

2 Click File > Export Map from the main menu.

3 Navigate to where you want to save the export file.

4 Click the Save as type arrow and click PDF.

5 Type a file name for the export file.

6 Click the Pages tab.

7 Choose what pages you want to export.

8 Click Save.

Comment: Data Driven Pages are best ...............................
i have exported 25000+ of maps at my University Lab (10 desktops) 
Thanks jdavid05 and PolyGeo